# why does the index of "list_of_letters" not update for every while loop with "guessed_letter_string"? The problem occurs in the Try: section

Tags: python

Hangman. As you probobly understand i am new to coding and python, sorry for bad code.
The best way i can think of to describe this problem is through the following way: In the "try:" section i try to `index = list_of_letters.index(guesssed_letter_string)`. i want to check if the guessed_letter_string is in list_of_letters: i earlier in the code translate the input from well the only input() in the code to guessed_letter_string (its the same thing). when you input a letter in the middel of the word it works like index[3] but when you input the first letter in the word the index locks at 0 and every other letter replaces it. is there a way to fix this

```
import random

list_of_words = ["mom", "dad", "sister", "brother"]
random_word = random.choice(list_of_words)
list_of_letters = list(random_word)

print(random_word)
print(list_of_letters)

rounds_failed = 1
rounds_max = 16

list_of_letters_guessed = []
under_grejer = []
count_of_right_letters_list = []

print(f"You have {rounds_max - rounds_failed} rounds left to find out the word")

for every in list_of_letters:
    under_grejer.extend("_")

while True:

    if rounds_failed == rounds_max:
        print("To many attempts, no more rounds")
        break

    if len(list_of_letters) == 0:
        print("YOU FUCKING WON")
        break

    print(f"This is round: {rounds_failed}")

    print(" ".join(under_grejer))

    print("Letters that are correct(not in order): "+", ".join(count_of_right_letters_list))
    print("List of letters guessed: "+", ".join(list_of_letters_guessed))
    guess = input("NAME A Letter: ")

    guess_letters_list = (list(guess))
    guess_count_letters = len(guess_letters_list)

    if guess_count_letters > 1:
        print("Dummy you just need to input a letter, nothing else")

    guesssed_letter_string = " ".join(guess_letters_list)
    try:
        index = list_of_letters.index(guesssed_letter_string)
        print("Congrats you got the letter: " + guesssed_letter_string)
        print(f"thats the {index + 1}nd letter in the word")
        rounds_failed += 1
        count_of_right_letters_list.extend(guesssed_letter_string)
        print(index)
        list_of_letters.pop(index)
        under_grejer[index] = guesssed_letter_string

    except ValueError:
        print("try again mate that letter was not in the word")
        list_of_letters_guessed.append(guesssed_letter_string)
        rounds_failed += 1
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the first letter only. Your problem is that with `list_of_letters.pop(index)` you remove the guessed letter form `list_of_letters`; parts of your code rely on this to check if you guessed all occurrences of that letter before already, but on the other hand this reduces the index of all letters behind the guessed one for later iterations.

For example, for `brother`, if you guess `r` it correctly says position 2, but if you then guess `o` next, it again says position 2 because your `list_of_letters` now reads `["b","o","t","h","e","r"]`.

You could either try to work with `list_of_letters_org = list_of_letters.copy()` which you will never change, and pick the right one for every task, or you could for example change the program structure by adding a list of booleans that store which letters were guessed already.